# Break the permission and assign new ones in itemadding event

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to break the inheritance of the current item and assign the new ones . I tried it using `ItemAdded` and it worked but the problem was it was taking time to assign the new permissions to the user and users were getting error after opening that item , it was opening after refreshing the page . so i tried putting **'synchronize'** in the xml file but still it dint work . so my last resort i thought would be to go ahead with `ItemAdding` ,

In `ItemAdded` : i was doing it this way

```
SPListItem ListItem = Web.Lists[properties.ListId].GetItemById(properties.ListItem.ID);
oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
 ListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);

SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = ListItem.RoleAssignments; 

for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 

{
SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
}
```

but i am not able to get the current item in `ItemAdding` event so how can i break inheritance and assign new ones in this event.

Answer (score 1):

Just be sure to get the values from `ItemAdded` event. Because when `ItemAdding`, the current item is not updated in the list yet and you cannot get the item values. The reason why that the values are not available is because they aren't exist yet.

Comment: @Mohammad Arif , i editted my question can you suggest on this.

Answer (score 1):

As you said it yourself in the question that the item has not yet been created hence you won't be able to get the item using `properties.Item`.

If you need to get the values of the columns then you would need to use

```
properties.AfterProperties["ColumnName"]
```

the statement `SPListItem item = properties.Item` would yield result for you in the ItemAdded event as by then the item would have been already created.

Comment: ,i editted my question can you suggest on this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the item value in `ItemAdding` event. You can refer this [BeforeProperties/AfterProperties in Event Receivers](http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2010/06/beforepropertiesafterproperties-in-event-receivers-i-always-forget-this/).

You can get the Value in `ItemAdded` event.

Let me know your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: @Akshay Morya , i editted my question can you suggest on this.

Answer (score 1):

Just to speed up the code in ItemAdded event, you can pass ListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false); - false flag will not inherit user/ groups from parent so for loop will be avoided. Later you can just start assigning roles to required users.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by using Sandbox or Farm solution. You can accomplish this using a `workflow` using `AppStep`.

Please refer the link for creating the workflow using [AppStep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx)

Or else try to refresh the page programattically at the end of the `ItemAdded` event.